# How to set "maxbibnames" inside a refsection using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to change the number of names printed in a local bibliography using `maxbibnames`, but it throws an error ("Package keyval Error: maxbibnames undefined."). What am I doing wrong?

Here's an MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{referenceA,
  author = {Anderson, Alice},
  title = {Generic Article Title A},
  journal = {Journal},
  year = {2022},
}
@article{referenceB,
  author = {Anderson, Alice and Author, Bob},
  title = {Generic Article Title B},
  journal = {Journal},
  year = {2024},
}
@article{referenceC,
  author = {Campbel, Carol and Author, Dave},
  title = {Generic Article Title C},
  journal = {Journal},
  year = {2024},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
    \small
    \nocite{referenceA}
    \nocite{referenceB}
    \nocite{referenceC}
    \newrefcontext[sorting=ynt]
    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
    \printbibliography[heading=none, maxbibnames=1]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Appendix E of the `biblatex` manual which shows the valid scopes of all options. `maxbibnames` is not an option to `\printbibliography`. It can be set globally, per-type or per-entry.

Comment: Thank you. That's a shame though. I wonder why that is. Can you explain what per-entry means/how you implement it?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it now using the "options" key in the bib-entries.